# Grant Project Tango Permissions with new deployments

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, google-project-tango

My Project Tango Java Application requests permission upon every deployment after a change to the code is made.  Since I'm building a robot and **deploying over wi-fi** I'm required to go to the robot and authorize the new application with every change.

Is there a way to avoid these recurring permission prompts during development?

Answer (score 0):

the Tango permission has to be accepted manually each time you re-install the app. There is no way around that..

Comment: Any insight as to why Tango uses a custom permissions scheme rather than allowing enforcement via AndroidManifest.xml like other GPS, camera, etc?

Comment: I think Project Tango's permission scheme is more inline with Android M where the permissions are requested contextually rather during installation.